# Dart versioning - no matching version

Tags: dart, versioning

In my angular2 project I don't manage to add the "google_maps: 3.1.0" dependency. 
It seems that this library is in conflict with "angular2: 2.0.0-beta.20".

The error message is :

```
Package code_transformers has no versions that match >=0.4.1 <0.5.0 derived from:
- build 0.3.0 depends on version ^0.4.1
```

However, "google_maps: 3.1.0" do not contain "code_transformers" or "build" package in its dependencies and transitive dependencies.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `pub get` or `pub upgrade` could not find a set of dependencies that are compatible.

Try to commenting out all dependencies except two and run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` again. Then add one dependency and run again and so on until you get the error. This way you can figure out what dependency causes the problem.

Don't use `any` as dependency constraint in your `pubspec.yaml`. This is known to cause troubles because `pub` has to analyze the whole search space which is gigantic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: When I only left the 2 dependencies (angular2: 2.0.0-beta.21,  google_maps: 3.1.0), the same error message shows up. What's weird it that code_transformers is not a dependency or transitive dependency of google_maps: 3.1.0. google_maps depends on js_wrapping wich depends on source_gen. source_gen currently has a dependency to code_transformers, but it hasn't in the version requested by google_maps: 3.1.0. It is possible "pub get" bugged ?

Comment: I had to add `  source_gen: ^0.5.1` to `dependency_overrides` to make `google_maps` work with `angular2`. It's a known issue of `js_wrapping`

Comment: Thanks, indeed i saw you already had this problem https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping/issues/10 :)

Comment: The error message from `pub get`/`pub upgrade` are often misleading as in your case. The Dart team is aware and are planning a bigger rework of the dependency resolver but that's quite a difficult task and good developers always have enough on their platter ...